# How can I open google drive project (android-quickstart)

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'd like to open a sample of google drive. But I can't it.

When I clicked user Google Id, the error message is

```
12-05 19:07:30.511 21192-21192/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart I/drive-quickstart: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{2397a78c: android.os.BinderProxy@2b9c8df4}, message=null}
12-05 19:07:30.881 21192-21192/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{20df1792 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2b33ccce {com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity}} show : true
```

I made my client ID and API key in google developer console.

How can I configure it in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=44749096405-3favhbhdu10s8bpglj5agucehbq859d0.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.1234567890" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
        </intent-filter>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                    return;
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");

                OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();

                ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                try {
                    outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                }

                MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();

                IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                        .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                        .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                        .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                    mBitmapToSave = null;

                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                            REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {

            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
        if (mBitmapToSave == null) {

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                    REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            return;
        }
        saveFileToDrive();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't present in public your API keys.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Can you try adding a case for REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION  in the switch statement present on onActivityResult. Try calling mGoogleApiClient.connect() again in that case. I hope that works.